# Missing local account after joining a domain

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain, local, accounts

I attempted to add my computer to a domain and now I cannot access any of the local accounts on my computer.

I had downloaded Windows Server 2012 and had two local accounts on it. Then, I attempted to access it using my friend's login information (that were linked to a Windows domain). I was prompted to restart my computer, and upon doing so, the icon for my local accounts were gone. Where before there were two local profiles I could access, now there was only an option to access an account linked to the domain. I tried using my local account login information, and it didn't work. I can log in using the administrative account of the domain. Also, if I try using my friend's account on my computer, it lets me log in.

The files from my local accounts are still on my computer. When logged in as the administrator, I can go to Users and from there access all of the files from the missing profiles. Is there any way for me to get my local accounts back?

Comment: First, confirm that the account(s) are actually still there (they should be).  Try running "NET USER" (without quotes) from the command-line, and then "NET USER <USERNAME>" to query a particular account.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question as you're rambling a bit. You `downloaded` Windows Server 2012? What does that mean? Also, joining a domain does not remove local user accounts. Your local user account is still there. Log on with your local user account by typing `.\username` in the username filed where `username` is your local user name.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try logging like this:

Username: \mymachinename\mylocalusername
Password mylocaluserpassword